# Different css behaviour for select - option

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I am using the following html statement:

```
<select ...>
   <option value=""></option>
   <option data-ng-repeat="type in xy" value="{{type.name}}" ng-style="{'border-left': '4px solid '+ type.color, 'color': type.color}" style="margin-bottom: 2px;"> {{type.name}}</option>
</select>
```

This is working fine with Firefox, a border is shown at the left side. 
With Chrome and IE 10 the border is not shown.
Does anyone know what I can do in order to make this continuous in every Browser?

Comment: May be chrome/ IE are not supporting this property as yet! Could you try to add -WebKit- in front of the property! I know it could sound silly but it's only a try

Answer (score 0):

[here is the browser support properites look at once](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_browsersupport.asp)

you need to specify

-webkit- chrome
-moz-   mozilla
-o- opera etc.